# Django: RadioSelect more granular control

Tags: python, django, templates, radio-button

I've a form

```
class DialogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    LISTING_CHOICES = ((1, _('Public')), (0, _('Unlisted')))

    first_question = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span4'})
    listing = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=LISTING_CHOICES)
```

I'm trying to get listing fields separately from template

```
{% for radio in dialog_form.listing %}
  {{ radio }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I got exception `Exception Value: 'BoundField' object is not iterable`

**Django Version**: **1.3.1**

How to work with `RadioSelect` widget to access its rendered sub-elements?

Sultan,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible in Django 1.3.1  Pretty sure you need version 1.4 to do this.

Comment: Django 1.4 support this feature, I think I have to do it manually then